# How to get the first n words from text stored in my DB in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I need to know how to get the first n words from text stored in my DB in PHP?

for example if there is some text in my DB like this one :

"word1 word2 word3 word4 text one test four five"

How I can get the first 4 or five words from this text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** function to split the string by space and get each word:

```
$words = 'word1 word2 word3 word4 text one test four five';
$words_array = explode(' ', $words);
```

And then you can use the **[`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)** function to get number of words:

```
print_r(array_chunk($words_array, 4, true));
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the MySQL [SUBSTRING INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function.

```
-- Will select everything up until the fifth space.
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(YourTextField, ' ', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because a regex expression is always nice to have:

```
if (preg_match('/([^\\s]*(?>\\s+|$)){0,4}/', $string, $matches)) {
    //result in $matches[0]
}
```